# Inequalities of expectations

Tags: probability, inequality

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$, integrable and everything. Is it true that,

$E(|XY|^2) \leq E(|X|^2) E(|Y|^2) $ ?

If not, can I use something so that I get,

$E|XY|^2 \leq (E|X|^p)^{1/p} E|Y|^2 \ $ ?

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: The first property $E[XY]^2 \leq E[X]^2 E[Y]^2$ is the well known Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: You need some parentheses.  I don't know whether the powers are inside or outside the expected values.

Comment: I mean $E[|XY|^2] \leq E[|X|^2]E[|Y|^2]$. I thought the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality was without the square on the left-hand side. I want it with the square.

Comment: **Hint**: Consider indicator functions.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [Holder's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality#Probability_measure)  associated with Probability measures.

Comment: @cardinal You can expand your comment in an answer.

Comment: There's no way the second inequality can hold. Let $X = Y = \lambda$ be a constant function. Then the inequality would read $\lambda^4 \leq \lambda \cdot \lambda^2 = \lambda^3$ which is false for all $\lambda > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality 
$$
E[|XY|^2] \leq E[|X|^2] E[|Y|^2]
$$
cannot be obtained in general. Indeed we can find an example of a pair of square-integrable random variables $X,Y$ for which the product is not square integrable, breaking the above inequality in a very fundamental way.

Proof: Let $\Omega = (0,1]$ and let $P$ be Lebesgue measure. Then let
$$
X(x) = Y(x) = \frac{1}{x^{1/4}}
$$
Note now that both $X,Y$ are $P$-square integrable (just integrate and see), yet $(XY)(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$ is not square integrable.

Comment: This is also an explicit counterexample to the second inequality you posited, for all $p < 4$.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make more comments so I write here. Sorry.
Taking indicator functions, f.ex: $X=1_A$ and $Y=1_B$. I obtain:

$P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)P(B)$
but is this true for any events $A$,$B$? (equality is true if they are independent)
In any case, is the inequality true?

I found out that, using Hölder one gets,

$E[|XY|^2] \leq \displaystyle \sup_{\omega \in \Omega}|X(\omega)|^2 E[|Y|^2]$

So $X\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. Is this the only way?

Comment: In a certain sense, yes! See my above answer. Practically speaking, the Holder inequality one derives is usually the optimal inequality one can obtain.

Answer (score 0):

Due to *Hölder's Inequality*, for $p,q \in (1,\infty)$ with $1/p +1/q=1$,

$$ 
E(|XY|) \leq [E(|X|^p)]^{1/p} [E(|Y|^q)]^{1/q}.
$$

Taking $p=q=2$ you get $E(|XY|)^2 = E(|X|^2) E(|Y|^2). $

Also note *Lyapunov’s Inequality:* If $0<s<t$, then
$$
[E(|X|^s)]^{1/s} \leq [E(|X|^t)]^{1/t}.
$$

Comment: I see nothing wrong in this answer, but it doesn't address the question at hand.

Comment: The question may ask $E(|X|^2) \leq E(|X|^p)^{2/p}$ for $p>2$, taking $Y$ to be the indicator function, that's why I noted Lyapunov’s Inequality.